# Best way to deal with DB Connection in the DAL - create or pass?

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection, data-access-layer

I want my Data Access Layer to be built very modular.
Therefore I have data retrieval methods that sometimes are called directly from the business layer and sometimes are called by other data retrieval methods to create object dependencies.

What is the best way to deal with database connections in the DAL?

**a) Create a new connection in every method and dispose it afterwards.**
*Good:* Easy to write and to work with.
*Bad:* Many connections are being opened and closed. (performance?)

**b) Pass the connection as an (optional) argument.**
*Good:* I could reuse an open connection for multiple commands.
*Bad:* I have to keep track of the ownership of the connection (who has to close it?) and cannot use the very neat "using" statements.

**c) Something else? (Connection as singleton maybe?)**

This is the first time I am writing a real DAL so I really could use some help from you experienced folks.

EDIT: As it seems to matter, it's an ASP.Net Website Project.

Comment: May be tangential, but FWIW, I would rather use nhibernate and let it hadndle all this. i.e. just work with session object provided by nhibernate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using ASP.Net, option A is your friend.

Create a new connection for each request, Dispose()-ing when the request is complete. Ensure that you use **identical** connect strings. The connections will (by default) remain open and available through a connection pool.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx for more information on connection pooling.

You pretty much have to do it this way in a web server so you don't have concurrency issues anyway. Everything needs to be thread-safe (you've got no idea how many concurrent worker threads are executing in your app).

[edited to add example code]

As an example, here's what I would consider to be a typical method to execute a stored procedure. This comes from a custom code generator I wrote — handwritten code will likely look a little different — but it should suffice to get the point across:

```
public int Exec(  int? @iPatientID )
{
  using ( SqlConnection  conn = new SqlConnection( this.ConnectString ) )
  using ( SqlCommand     cmd  = conn.CreateCommand() )
  using ( SqlDataAdapter sda  = new SqlDataAdapter( cmd ) )
  {
    cmd.CommandText = STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME ;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;

    if ( this.TimeoutInSeconds.HasValue )
    {
      cmd.CommandTimeout = this.TimeoutInSeconds.Value ;
    }

    //
    // 1. @iPatientID
    //
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter( @"@iPatientID" , SqlDbType.Int ) ;
    if ( @iPatientID == null )
    {
      p1.Value = System.DBNull.Value ;
    }
    else
    {
      p1.Value = @iPatientID ;
    }
    cmd.Parameters.Add( p1 ) ;

    // add return code parameter
    SqlParameter pReturnCode = new SqlParameter() ;
    pReturnCode.SqlDbType    = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int ;
    pReturnCode.Direction    = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue ;
    cmd.Parameters.Add( pReturnCode ) ;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet() ;

    conn.Open() ;
    sda.Fill( ds ) ;
    conn.Close() ;

    this.ResultSet  = ( ds.Tables.Count > 0 ? ds.Tables[0] : null ) ;
    this.ReturnCode = (int) pReturnCode.Value ;

  }

  return this.ReturnCode ;

}
```

Comment: Yes, its an ASP.Net Website. Thanks for the link and the answer. But I dont understand how passing the connection can be a concurrency issue?

Comment: @atticae: it would only become a concurrency issue if the connection object ends up getting used by multiple threads. Whether this happens would depend on how your code is structured, but it's far less likely to happen accidentally if you're creating and disposing the connection within the context of a data-access method.

Comment: The only time that you might want to pass the SqlConnection around would be if multiple DAL methods needed to participate in the same SqlTransaction.  This is probably best avoided.

Answer (score 2):

We use a variant of option A.

We actually use Entity Framework so that we can leverage LINQ and such. Entity Framework manages its own connection pooling, so creating and deleting contexts is cheap. We then leverage Dependency Injection to manage the actual creation of the connection, like so:

```
public class MyDao 
{
    IFactory<MyDataContext> _contextFactory;
    public MyDao(IFactory<MyDataContext> contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public Foo GetFooById(int fooId)
    {
        using (var context = _contextFactory.Get())
        {
            return context.Foos.Single(f => f.FooId == fooId);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, if we ever decide that we want to create our contexts using a different connection string, or even something more tricky, we can simply change the dependency-injection bindings in one place, rather than having to find every call to `new MyDataContext()`.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to have a connection pool where you can get your connections. Let the conenction pool handle the lifetime of the connections, and get already open ones when you need them!
An example of this is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Most providers pool connections anyway, either at the ODBC level or the .NET level.  So option A is both safer and probably equally good performance-wise.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

And: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Use all Three**

Write connection as optional parameter.  If none(null) is passed in, create a connection from some (singleton, maybe) shared source so all your DAL classes are creating connections with same exact connection strings (for pooling as mentioned by @Nicholas Carey).  Open and close it only if you create it.

If a connection is passed in, assume it is already open, and do not close it.  At a higherlevel, when you call this method, you can use a using statement to handle closing of the connection.